# how to replicate browser crash for automation testing

Tags: selenium, testing, browser, automated-tests

I am currently working on a functionality were i am auto saving content while editing a post. The functionality is expected to work even on browser crash. My question is there a way to automate(selenium or similar) and test the browser crash.

Comment: Selenium can save the cookies so the session and can inject those cookies to new browser session but once the browser close the selenium will also stop as the port on which he was driving will be going to close. 

I haven't try but you can save the cookie from first browser then open a another browser inject that cookie and crash your first browser .. may be it help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would inject an exception to crash the window and work in a new window to check the recovery. It's not exactly a browser crash but close:

```
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
driver.get("https://www.google.co.uk");

// crash the window
((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript(
    "window.open();" +
    "window.stop();" +
    "setTimeout(function(){" +
      "document.open();" +
      "document.write('<script>throw new Error();</script>');" +
      "document.close();},0);");

// close the window
Object[] handles = driver.getWindowHandles().toArray();
driver.close();

// switch to the new window and reload the page
driver.switchTo().window(handles[1].toString());
driver.get("https://www.google.co.uk");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Few ways are:
1. Reload browser for multiple times or indefinitely.
2. Paste very big texts (text bigger than the size of input text fields) in input texts.
3. Click submit button multiple times in a quick succession.
4. Open many instances of same browser, reduce the available memory to be used by browser.
etc.. 

Hope this helps !!
```